# How to resolve: IllegalStateException: Config is null, please ensure that your init(config) method calls super.init(config)

Tags: java, exception, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I'm developing a MVCPortlet. I have a link in my view.jsp which calls a method in portlet class in liferay.

```
<portlet:actionURL var="listComplexURL" name="listComplex"/>    
<a href="<%=listComplexURL%>">Comlex</a>
This is the <b>Refahi</b> portlet.
```

And this is the corresponding method in portlet class:

```
public void listComplex(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    RFH_Complex rfh_complex = new RFH_Complex();
    ArrayList<Complex> complexList = rfh_complex.getComplexList();
    actionRequest.setAttribute("complexList", complexList);
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/complex.jsp");
}
```

I deploy the portlet and click on the link, but I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Config is null, please ensure that your init(config) >method calls super.init(config)

Even when I implement the init() method and call super.init() inside it, I still get this error.

Here is my getComplexList() method:

```
public ArrayList<Complex> getComplexList() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    ArrayList<Complex> complexList = new ArrayList<Complex>();
    ResultSet rs = dbOperation.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM rfh_complex");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        Complex complex = new Complex(rs.getInt("PKComplexID"), rs.getString("ComplexName"), 
                rs.getString("ComplexCity"), rs.getInt("IsActive"));
        complexList.add(complex);
    }
    return complexList;
}
```

Complex.jsp contains this line of code:

```
ArrayList<Complex> complexList = (ArrayList)actionRequest.getAttribute("complexList");
```

Comment: Can you clarify - are you implementing the init() method taking a config parameter ? And is that definitely non-null ?

Comment: can you provide snippet of your init() method?

Comment: No, I don't pass config parameter. When I comment the code inside listComplex() the error disappears. I updated my question and I put getComplexList of RFH_Complex class.

Comment: @Karadous: can you paste your 'portlet.xml' file or check your `<init-param>` if it is specified. can you paste the stackTrace of the error?

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature for listComplex is wrong . It should only throw IOException and PortletException. You should handle the SQLException and ClassNotFoundException in the method body or somewhere else(I try that my controller never throws SQLException). There is no need to override init method in your case.

Comment: When I remove the code inside listComplex except the last line everything goes ok.

Comment: By the way I have this code in my complex.jsp: ArrayList<Complex> complexList = (ArrayList)actionRequest.getAttribute("complexList");

Comment: Its not because of that. If you remove the first two lines of code where in you are getting values from database it should work fine. To test , just pass a dummy arraylist with some values and see, it will work fine

Comment: I think I found the problem. I use getInitParameter() inside a class constructor. Can I use this method in my classes or I should use it inside portlet class?

Comment: I am not sure. It will be of great help if you can paste the whole of your portlet class source code. We never write constructor in our custom portlet class

Comment: I didn't write a constructor for portlet class. I have a class called DBOperation. Inside the constructor of this class I'm using getInitParameter() method.